# how to change the height of ngdialog

Tags: angularjs

I want to set size of `ngDialog`.  When I write the code below

```
ngDialog.open(
    template: 'adddUserDialog',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
    width:800px,
    height:800px
});
```

I find the height configuration doesn't take effect but the width configuration works properly. Maybe `ngDialog` open function doesn't support the parameter of height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [ng-dialog options](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#options) you can see that it does not accept height. However, you can set a custom class to the wrapper, which means you should be able to set a height through a class definition as follows:

*js*

```
ngDialog.open({
  template: 'adddUserDialog',
  className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
  appendClassName: 'ngdialog-custom',
  width:800px
});
```

*css*

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-custom .ngdialog-content {
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I have solved this problem with your help,thank you very much.

Comment: Great, glad to have helped you. Please accept my answer to close your question.